# Dynamically Added button, jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been going through my dynamically added code and changing everything that was using .click() to use .on("click") and its been working great but now I've run into something that I am not sure how to convert to dynamically added compatible.

Here is the code:  This is a function in javascript that is called when a button named "Add" or "Remove" is clicked (these buttons are also dynamically added after another button is clicked)

```
    function row_add_remove(sname, snum, count, type) {
    if (type == "add") {
        var selectbox = '<select id="qty_'+snum+'_'+count+'" name="qty_'+snum+'_'+count+'">';
        for (i=1;i<16;i++){selectbox += '<option value='+i+'>'+i+'</option>';}
        selectbox += '</select>';
        if (count > 1) {
            $("#tr_"+sname+"_"+(count-1)).after('<tr id="tr_'+sname+'_'+count+'"><td>'+selectbox+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=text id="item_'+sname+'_'+count+'" name="item_'+snum+'_'+count+'" size="70" placeholder="Item '+count+'" /></td></tr>');
            $("#toprow"+snum+"_count").html("("+count+")");
        }
    }
    if (type == "remove") {
        if (count == 1) {
            $("#"+sname).hide();
            $("#toprow"+snum+"_count").html("");
            $("#td_"+sname+"_"+count).remove();
            $("#ph_order_div").show();
            count--;
        }
        if (count > 1) {
            $("#tr_"+sname+"_"+count).remove();
            count--;
            $("#toprow"+snum+"_count").html("("+count+")");
        }
        if (count < 0) {count = 0;}
    }
}
```

The problem (I think, maybe its more than this) is the .after() doesn't fire.  Now i'm not sure if the problem lies with that or with the whole code but when I click the Add button its not adding another TR after the one that is shown by default.

This code works great when NOT dynamically added so can anyone help me with what I need to change to get the above function to work when the buttons that call it and the TR's that it tries to modify are dynamically added?

Here is the code that is fired when the buttons are clicked:

```
    whatmeatfield = $("#meat_field_count").html();      
$(document).on("click", "#add_btn_1", function() {
    if (whatmeatfield <= 0) {whatmeatfield = 1;}
    whatmeatfield++;
    row_add_remove("meatseafood",1,whatmeatfield,"add");
});
$(document).on("click", "#remove_btn_1", function() {
    row_add_remove("meatseafood",1,whatmeatfield,"remove");
    whatmeatfield--;
    if (whatmeatfield <=0) {whatmeatfield = 1;}
});
```

Comment: This sounds like a delegation issue. For syntax see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `.after()`, there is typo mistake in `<input type=text` there should be quote like `<input type="text"`

You have not define `whatmeatfield`  variable. it should be

```
var whatmeatfield
```

Also you are directly passing html of some element id, you need to `parse` it to `integer`. like

```
var whatmeatfield = parseInt($("#meat_field_count").html()) ;
```

This may help you to solve your issues

Comment: I marked this one as the answer because it was the closest to the actual problem.
The problem was, my variable "whatmeatfield" was being defined in JS when the page first loads, NOT during the clicking of the buttons.  So since the fields were being dynamically added, when the page first loads the "meat_field_count" ID doesn't exist, therefore was not being set and therefore was not recognized by the code when the buttons were clicked and was being sent as "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The problem may occur becouse of two things.

1. You're using id selector and you're porobably adding another button with the same id and as far as html spec says id should be unique.

What can you do?
Change ID to CLASS.

2. The problem occurs becouse you're changing the id to schema like #remove_btn_1, #remove_btn_2, #remove_btn_3 and therefore you do not have any handler for this buttons.

What can you do?
Change selector from "#remove_btn_1" to "[id*=remove_btn_]"

Of course same with #add_btn_

Post me back if it was helpful.